# vb2010 - TextBox1.Text from MS Access record

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I am new to vb2010 and have been successful with google searches for all my previous problems but this one i cannot make any traction on so I am looking for a little help on the correct syntax.

```
Public Class Form2


    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'IRuleDataSet.Stnds' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.StndsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.IRuleDataSet.Stnds)


        'Populates listbox1 with data from iRuleDataSet table
        ListBox1.DataSource = IRuleDataSet.Stnds
        ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Standards"
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0

    End Sub


    Private Sub StndsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Me.Validate()
        Me.StndsBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.IRuleDataSet)

    End Sub

    Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
        End
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Label2.Text = ListBox1.Text & " IRule"
'~~>This is where I am stuck
'~~>    TextBox1.Text = IRuleDataSets.Stnds.IRule.ListBox1.SelectedIndex bah i can't get this ):
    End Sub
End Class
```

in form 2, I have loaded an access database into a DataSet labeld IRuleDataSet.Stnds

Table = Stnds

Field = IRule

Record Position = ListBox1.SelectedIndex

what would be the correct syntax or naming convention/logic to have the corresponding text for the record position in Field: "IRule" that the user selects in ListBox1 to display in TextBox1?

This isn't for any schooling subject or anything like that. This is merely a learning exercise for myself to put together a GUI for calculations that are currently done in an overly complicated xls file at my work, so any help would be appreciated. I don't know if it is becoming too late for me or not but I just cannot seem to find the correct way to approach this seemingly simple task.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

AHA!

sure enough as soon as i post a question i find the correct solution

```
TextBox1.Text = IRuleDataSet.Stnds(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)(2).ToString
```

what this does, it sets TextBox1 text to look in to the imported access file (as IRuleDataSet.Stnds) then looks at the 'row' (ListBox1.SelectedIndex), and then the column number (2). i know this is 2 because when i put in my dummy data in the database, the field of interest was the second column.

i hope this helps future googlers (: